# database view creation issue

Tags: sql, database

I have many users with unique userID in table-1 with their specifications, I have other table-2 that Supervisors choose hours that users work. (I connect userID of table-2 to table-1 and it's ok)
supervisors are many so maybe their is many row with different hour for same useriD. So I create view  with

```
 select w_userid,sum(w_hour)as total from Workk group by w_userid
```

for show me one userID with sum of his hours. But I cant add it in database layer.

Comment: Welcome on SO consider reading the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question si vague and it seems you haven’t tried anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and what do you mean exactly by 'cant add it in database layer'? An error stacktrace and how you tried to solve it yourself is helpful.

Comment: please update your question with a minimal database schema, the request that "does not work" or the expected result. fwiw, "add it in database layer" is meaningless. also try to find a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join two tables using **'inner join'** and you have to use a **'where'** condition. In **where** condition use **'AND'** to check its the same person using the employee id and then sum the total working hours.